# Working with Joins in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following set of tables with the attached query. Evidently, I'm stuffing too many `AND` clauses into this and now no results are valid even though are results. Shown below are the Diagram and SQL I'm using.

[image: MySQL Database Model-hidden fields aren't vital.]

```
SELECT p.products_id, pd.language_id, pd.products_name,
       pd.products_description, pd.products_url, p.products_quantity,
       p.products_model, p.products_image, p.products_price, p.products_virtual,
       p.products_weight, p.products_date_added, p.products_last_modified,
       p.products_date_available, p.products_status, p.manufacturers_id,
       p.products_quantity_order_min, p.products_quantity_order_units, p.products_priced_by_attribute,
       p.product_is_free, p.product_is_call, p.products_quantity_mixed,
       p.product_is_always_free_shipping, p.products_qty_box_status, p.products_quantity_order_max, p.products_sort_order, 

FROM `magez_products` p, `magez_products_description` pd
       WHERE p.products_id = pd.products_id
       AND p.products_id = 186
       AND p.products_id = cfv.products_id 
       AND cfv.nation_id = cfvn.nation_id
       AND cfv.clan_id = cfvc.clan_id
       AND cfv.rarity_id = cfvr.rarity_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help, I too was old-school ANSI format... You'll find more current queries written using JOINS between the tables and only apply the "AND" where you actually want to "restrict".  Sometimes, this could be directly at the join instead of the primary "from" table.  Also, by doing as a join, you see exactly how table "A" connects to table "B", and I try to keep the A = B comparison in the same sequence as the tables are listed...  Left-side table on left side of =, right-side table on right side of = such as

```
SELECT 
      p.products_id, 
      pd.language_id, 
      pd.products_name,
      pd.products_description, 
      pd.products_url, 
      p.products_quantity,
      p.products_model, 
      p.products_image, 
      p.products_price, 
      p.products_virtual,
      p.products_weight, 
      p.products_date_added, 
      p.products_last_modified,
      p.products_date_available, 
      p.products_status, 
      p.manufacturers_id,
      p.products_quantity_order_min, 
      p.products_quantity_order_units, 
      p.products_priced_by_attribute,
      p.product_is_free, 
      p.product_is_call, 
      p.products_quantity_mixed,
      p.product_is_always_free_shipping, 
      p.products_qty_box_status, 
      p.products_quantity_order_max, 
      p.products_sort_order
   FROM 
      magez_products p
         JOIN magez_products_description pd
            on p.products_id = pd.products_id
         JOIN magez_cfv_cards cfv
            on p.products_id = cfv.products_id
            JOIN magez_cfv_nations cfvn
               on cfv.nation_id = cfvn.nation_id
            JOIN magez_cfv_clans cfvc
               on cfv.clan_id = cfvc.clan_id
            JOIN magez_cfv_rarity cfvr
               on cfv.rarity_id = cfvr.rarity_id
   where
      p.products_id = 186
```

Notice the formatting I have, it correlates to your table structures... A joined to B, B joined to C, D and E on respective columns.  The WHERE clause is simple on the exact criteria you want...

Now, if you only wanted certain other elements, you can just add your "AND" to that component's JOIN criteria.

Answer (score 1):

What i am doing usually in these cases is start with smaller query (e.g. one AND) and increase the query more and more, until you will see where it starts to have "no results". otherwise it is very difficult to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the complete select or mysql should complain, because the select is missing cfv, cfvn, cfvc and cfvr tables.

You could resolve it by removing `and ...` one by one from the end of the `where` clause and see where the result starts having rows again.

One problem might be a join table (e.g. pd, cfv) missing a `products_id` for example.

Another resolution could be to replace the inner joins by left joins, depending on your requirements of course.

Comment: I completely forgot that I removed the WHERE statement originally. Sorry about that.

Comment: And what happens then? Do you have the desired result set?

Comment: Not entirely. I did have to use the join statement as the accepted shows but this put me in the right area.

Answer (score 1):

you need the join statement

```
SELECT p.products_id, pd.language_id, pd.products_name,
   pd.products_description, pd.products_url, p.products_quantity,
   p.products_model, p.products_image, p.products_price, p.products_virtual,
   p.products_weight, p.products_date_added, p.products_last_modified,
   p.products_date_available, p.products_status, p.manufacturers_id,
   p.products_quantity_order_min, p.products_quantity_order_units,         
p.products_priced_by_attribute,
   p.product_is_free, p.product_is_call, p.products_quantity_mixed,
   p.product_is_always_free_shipping, p.products_qty_box_status,                                                                               p.products_quantity_order_max,
p.products_sort_order, 

FROM `magez_products` p
join `magez_products_description` pd
on p.products_id = pd.products_id
   AND p.products_id = 186
   AND p.products_id = cfv.products_id      <-------------- what is cfv  join   on that too !!!!!!!!!!
   AND cfv.nation_id = cfvn.nation_id
   AND cfv.clan_id = cfvc.clan_id
   AND cfv.rarity_id = cfvr.rarity_id
```